# AngularJs: $watch not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I know this have been asked many times, but any of the solutions exposed seem to work for me. I have this HTML

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <h4>{{size}}</h4>
  <input type="range" ng-model="size" min="1" max="100" />
  <div font-scale="{{size}}">I'm some text</div>
</body>
```

The input works, the value changes and it is actually binding to {{size}} correctly.

Then I have my directive:

```
MyApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.size = 30;
});


MyApp.directive('fontScale', function(){
 return {
   link: function(scope, el, attrs){
     scope.$watch(attrs['fontScale'], function(newVal){
       console.log('testing');
       el.css('font-size', newVal+'px');
     });
    }
   }
 });
```

The 'testing' shows up in console only once, when the page loads, but when changing the value through the slider, it doesn't. But it DOES bind the value of {{size}} correctly.

Adding 'TRUE' as a third parameter doesn't work, and curiously, the tutorial I'm learning this from works with the same code!

What am I missing?

Comment: The scope in the directive is not the scope in your controller. The directive thus has no clue about the property 'size' so you can not watch a property that is not there. a) ensure that 'size' is available in your scope (read about isolated scopes therefore) and b) specify the watcher as scope.$watch('size'...)

Comment: The 'size' in the $scope is only for initialization and showing the value. The directive is actually getting the value from the 'font-scale' parameter.. The $scope.size not being in the same scope, shouldn't be a issue. Or at least that is how I understand it if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size property is available in your directives scope (as stated in your comment). Then the following should work:

```
scope.$watch('size', function(newVal) {
    el.css('font-size', newVal+'px');
}
```